# Getting the Visibility of a Handler

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

Out base plug-ins define commands and handler, which the application later enables or disables or makes (in)visible. Now I'm trying to evaluate a double click and need to access a command. That's easy:

```
private boolean executeCommand(String commandId) {
    IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService) getSite().getService(IHandlerService.class);
    try {
        handlerService.executeCommand(commandId, null);
        return true;
    } catch (ExecutionException | NotDefinedException | NotEnabledException
            | NotHandledException e) {
        MessageUtil.logError(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is: There are two handlers ("edit" and "view") which are possible to be executed, and I want to only execute "edit" when it's there, else "view".

```
    ICommandService commandService = (ICommandService) getSite().getService(ICommandService.class);
    Command command = commandService.getCommand(commandId);
    IHandler handler = command.getHandler();
```

I tried asking the command for `isDefined()`, `isEnabled()` and `isHandled()` and the handler for `isEnabled()` and `isHandled()`, but everything returns true.

How do I find out if the handler is visible?

Comment: I don't understand why just executing the command is not enough. That should run the handler which is active for the current context.

Comment: @greg-449 Because there are two commands. I need to call the second if the first does not contain a handler (because it was deactivated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally found the answer:

```
public boolean isCommandEnabled(String commandId) {
    final IWorkbenchActivitySupport activitySupport = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActivitySupport();
    final IActivityManager activityManager = activitySupport.getActivityManager();

    for (String activityId : (Set<String>) activitySupport.getActivityManager().getDefinedActivityIds()) {
        // we iterate through all activities...
        IActivity activity = activityManager.getActivity(activityId);
        for (IActivityPatternBinding activityBinding : (Set<IActivityPatternBinding>) activity.getActivityPatternBindings()) {
            // ...and check if one of the bindings match the command...
            if (isMatch(activityBinding, commandId) && !activity.isEnabled()) {
                // ... to get the command's enablement
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // if no activity was found to disable the command, it's enabled by default
    return true;
}

private static boolean isMatch(IActivityPatternBinding activityBinding, String toMatch) {
    return activityBinding.getPattern().matcher(toMatch).matches();
}
```

I don't really know if this is normal or just for our applications, but the `commandId` in this is case is something along the lines of `org.acme.plugin/org.acme.plugin.commands.commandId`.